# How to handle asynchronny in two separate files?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, include, static-linking

I currently have two files.

1. **delay.js** : For demonstration purposes to simplify the example, let's say the file contains a single asynchronous function. *(Obviously actual file is much more complex)*

   ```
   var delay = (ms) => (new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)));

   delay(4000)
      .then( () => console.log('delay.js has finished');
   ```
2. **gravity.js**: A simple canvas playground:

```js
// Canvas settings:
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// in case somebody re-sizes the window
canvas.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
});


function CanvasEl(x, y, v, width, height, f, g){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.v = v;

  this.draw = function(){
    c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, width, height);
  }

  this.gravitate = function(){

    if ( this.y + height >= window.innerHeight){
      this.v = -this.v;
      this.v = this.v * f;
    } else {
      this.v += g;
    }

    this.y += this.v;

    this.draw();
  }

}

var rect = new CanvasEl(0, 0, 2, window.innerWidth, 50, 0.76, 0.56);

function animate(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate); // recursive (loop) for animation

  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  rect.gravitate();
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

---

> **Now what I want to achieve:**
>   Is to somehow link these two files together, basically once `delay.js` finishes, only then `gravity.js`
>   should fire.

Is there a way I could somehow apply `.then( () => animate())`, without having to copy-paste the `gravity.js` code into `delay.js`? *-- basically I'd prefer to keep the two files separate*

---

I am aware of `Promise.all` and `await` commands, but I can't figure out a way, how could I apply them without having the code in one single file.

Comment: What does your actual file do and why does an otherwise completely independent module need to wait for it? Or is it not really independent actually? Please elaborate so that we can suggest the most appropriate approach for your situation.

Comment: @Bergi Uhm, basically an intro to a website that I always want to finnish before firing the other script. I know in the example I provided there is no reason for them to wait, but I just used these two code snippets to simplify the issue. Proper solution here is indeed the Module approach you suggested. Thank you :)

Comment: You mean, like a loading screen? I guess events and a static promise are fine for that. The promise has the advantage that it persists and if something else is loaded at an indeterminate time (like after the event would have fired), it can still chain onto the promise and would get executed at the right time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to store the promise that indicates the result of `delay.js` in a global variable:

```
// delay.js
…
var gravityResult = delay(4000)
   .then( () => console.log('delay.js has finished');
```

Then you can use that in the other file:

```
// gravity.js
…
gravityResult.then(animate); // instead of calling `animate()` right away
```

Name the global variable appropriately (or even use a proper module system to avoid globals and get declarative dependencies), and if possible resolve the promise with the value that the animation is actually waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `gravity.js` listen to an event on `window`, and activate its code only when that event fires. When `delay` is finished, trigger that event, so that `gravity.js` sees it and starts running.

```js
console.log('start');

// delay.js
var delay = (ms) => (new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)));
delay(1000)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('delay.js has finished');
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('delayDone'));
  });
  
// gravity.js
window.addEventListener('delayDone', () => {
  console.log('running gravity code');
  // insert gravity code here
});
```

An event and listener isn't *necessary* - another possibility would be to put a `Promise` on a globally accessible object and have `gravity.js` call `.then` on it:

```js
console.log('start');

// delay.js
var delay = (ms) => (new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)));
window.delayProm = delay(1000)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('delay.js has finished');
  });
  
// gravity.js
window.delayProm
  .then(() => {
    console.log('running gravity code');
    // insert gravity code here
  });
```

But this pollutes the global scope.

Comment: Out of your personal developer experience, what would you say is the "correct" approach? Global variable seems much more intuitive, but then again, most javascript learning sources dislike engaging with the global scope (and for a good reason from what I've seen). I've yet to tackle this sort of issue, so I'd rather pick up on a proper way to do this thing moving forward

Comment: @Rawrplus Globals are the only way to have two different scripts communicate. Use a module system if you want to avoid this. Notice that even if you use the `window` events, their names are a global namespace.

Comment: @Rawrplus For a large page, many globals may well be a problem. Like Bergi mentioned, a module bundler like Webpack would be the most elegant solution, but you might not consider it useful enough for smaller pages without many interconnected parts.